# How to debug SharePoint stored procedures with Visual Studio 2010 on SQL Server 2008 R2?

Tags: debugging, sharepoint, stored-procedures

I'm looking for a way to debug the stored procedures that SharePoint uses. I would like to get an idea what is happening on the database side. The COM Exception message is pig-useless (0x8004005, which means generic problem - hurrah) and I would like to see what is going wrong on the other side as I can't muck around in the COM Component itself.
While I followed the description on how to setup VS for debugging the SQL Server they somehow all assume I can call the stored proc myself.  I'm looking for either a Debugger.break()-style T-SQL call or something similar. Any ideas?

Comment: What is the error in the SharePoint ULS Logs? What does the event log say? What is the exact exception? Did you turn of custom errors in the web.config? In either case: SQL Server Profiler is your friend, you'll be able to see everything which is happening.

Comment: Hi, I'm pretty sure I know what the exact issue is. I developed a custom list and added a new calculated field. Since then I've been getting the error 

System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Cannot complete this action. Please try again. [Managed code transition] at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.AddOrUpdateItem

It's obvious it is something I've done and that the field is setup wrongly, but how and in which fashion is vexing me. I was looking for a more directed fashion than just guesing what SharePoint doesn't like.

Comment: You still didn't answer my questions. What is the error in the ULS logs?

Comment: Hi moontear - it is in the comment. Probably a bit difficult to see **System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Cannot complete this action. Please try again. [Managed code transition] at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.AddOrUpdateItem **

Comment: Sorry, I did see that. I'm just wondering whether anything before that exception can give you more information. Generally SharePoint tells you what is wrong, especially when you are just working with a calculated field. Errors with that field should all be catched. Otherwise you will have to resort to using SQL Profiler to see the incoming requests - if the problem lies in the DB at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can debug a stored procedure on SERVER only and NOT on CLIENT.

If sql server is installed on server, and in your local PC you have only SQL Server Management Studio is installed, you can not debug stored procedure in your local PC.

You need to go to server and there you can debug stored procedure in SQL Server Management Studio like this:

1. Open stored procedure in SQL Server Management Studio.
2. Click "Start Debugging"  from Debug menu.

Comment: Hi Amit, thanks for the pointer ... I have a all-in-one Developer System where I'm also Administrator, sysadmin on the Server, etc. Do you have another idea what it might be?